# Trigger sumar 2 columnas de tablas diferentes

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench, mysqldb

Hola estoy intentando hacer un disparador para que cada vez que inserte un registro en la tabla pagos coja el valor del campo catidad y se lo añada al campo cantidad_pagada de la tabla polizas cuyo campo pagos.id_polizas y polizas.id sean el mismo del ultimo insert en la tabla pagos, no se por que pero me da error, todos los campos son varchar(45) menos los campos polizas.id y pagos.id_pago que son int auto incremento

```
    DELIMITER $$
BEGIN
DECLARE id_pol varchar(45);
DECLARE cantidadPagada integer;
DECLARE nuevoPago integer;
DECLARE suma integer;
SELECT pagos.id_poliza INTO id_pol from pagos ORDER BY pagos.id_pago DESC LIMIT 1;


SELECT pagos.cantidad INTO nuevoPago from pagos ORDER BY pagos.id_pago DESC LIMIT 1;


SELECT polizas.cantidad_pagada into cantidadPagada FROM polizas where polizas.id =id_pol;

suma=nuevoPago+cantidadPagada;
UPDATE polizas SET polizas.cantidad_pagada=suma where polizas.id=id_pol;
END $$
```

[image: el error]
[image: esta es la tabla polizas]
[image: esta es la tabla pagos]
[image: metodo para crear el trigger en phpmyadmin]

Comment: Ayudaría mucho que agregues el error exacto que obtienes

Comment: @BetaM ya esta actualizado

Comment: E! mensaje de error te está diciendo que hay error de sintaxis en tu sentencia de creación del TRIGGER. Ese código no aparece completo en la pregunta, pulsa en [edit] y pon el código completo.

Comment: @A.Cedano ese es todo el codigo del trigger no hay mas

Comment: Falta la parte del `CREATE TRIGGER ...` No la veo.

Comment: @A.Cedano acabo de subir una nueva foto de como creo el trigger desde la linea 1

Comment: ya esta solucionado, el problema se solucionaba eliminando los delimitadores y dejando solo begin y end

Comment: A ver, ni siquiera queda claro cómo se llama el TRIGGER. En el mensaje de error dice que hay un error de sintaxis en un TRIGGER llamado `pagosPolizasActualizar`, luego, en la imagen de la edición parecería que el TRIGGER se llama `actualizarPagoPoliza`. Entonces, ¿tienes dos disparadores en la misma tabla?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120094/discussion-between-borja-lorenzo-and-a-cedano).

Answer (score 0):

El problema se solucionaba eliminando los delimitadores y dejando solo begin y end como primera y ultima linea

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/256980)

Comment: hombre yo he hecho eso y ha funcionado, el error ha desaparecido y el trigger a funcionado, si despues de que se solucionara al hacer eso , no es una solucion que venga dios y lo vea

Comment: La respuesta no necesariamente esta mal, simplemente quedaría mucho mejor si incluyes un ejemplo de la solución o amplias un poco mas tu respuesta haciéndola mas clara. Esto por si algún usuario tiene un problema parecido tu respuesta le ayude de mejor manera, así mismo si tienes escrita una respuesta mas completa recibirás mas puntos a favor.

Comment: El comentario que recibiste por mi parte anteriormente es porque en su momento consideré tu respuesta mas como un comentario que como respuesta. Saludos ;)

Comment: @Israel-ICM Aaaaah entiendo gracias por la aportacion luego intentare pasar una captura de como quedo ^^